# POWERPNT.EXE UI automation get children of PodiumParent panel using inspect.exe

Tags: powerpoint, ui-automation, pywinauto, inspect.exe

When I use inspect.exe to inspect the presentation window of powerpnt.exe, it can NOT list any element of the window, but after enable "Watch Focus" of inspect.exe and click on presentation window, inspect.exe can show detail elements of the presentation window.

My question is, how to show detail elements of the presentation window use pywinauto or win32 API.

Comment: Inspect.exe doesn’t use Win32 API, it uses MS UI Auyomation API (UIAutomationCore.dll COM library). Pywinauto should use Application(backend=“uia”) and dump_tree() method to list a hierarchy. Sorry, no much time to prepare the code. Typing from phone...

Comment: Also PowerPoint supports IDispatch COM interface which is an object model that can be automated through win32com.client.Dispath(“PowerPoint.Application”) or something like that.

Comment: ProviderDescription: "[pid:1956,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Unidentified Provider (unmanaged:mso.dll)]"
Detail elements seems has different UIA provider, it's not load by default, I guess.